# How can I change these colors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, fedora, eclipse-neon

I'm running fedora 24 and having a bit of a problem with some eclipse colors.

Anyone knows which color I need to change in `Window > Preferences > Appearance > colors and fonts` so that the font color in `Show List` is not white with a white background?

[image: see pic here]

Comment: Which version of eclipse?  Recent versions of eclipse don't have that setting anymore.  Those colors are controlled by themes, and themes aren't user customizable from the settings page.

Comment: The version is Eclipse Neon.

Comment: Even Eclipse Mars also has this problem on Fedora 24

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix.

Using `env SWT_GTK3=1 /home/path/to/eclipse` to start Eclipse solves the problem.